# added a css background, how to entirely remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery .css property to add a background

```
myobj.css('background', '#AE0000');
```

This results in this style html being added to the markup

```
style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(174, 0, 0);"
```

Later on, I want to remove this background. I thought that setting css background to white `myobj.css('background', '#FFFFFF');` would work, but unfortunately, this creates problems because the div has white background as opposed to nothing.

```
style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);"
```

Is there a similar way with jquery to entirely remove the `background` property of the CSS? like `style=""`

Comment: If possible can you just swap classes with css written for the class you need?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LCqn3/ will this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answer**

```
myobj.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
```

**Long Answer**

I'd suggest for better maintainability, use css classes for things like this:

```
.active { background:#AE00000 }
```

then in your javascript

```
myobj.addClass('active');
```

to toggle off

```
myobj.removeClass('active');
```

This has the benefit of you not having to worry about changing the css value (if you use `css()`) everytime there's change in your design or if you need to add more markup to that particular element.

For example, in the end you need to use background, font-size and color, in your js:

```
myobj.css({'background':'#aaa', 'font-size':'15px', 'color':'red'});
```

Then everytime you need to toggle off:

```
myobj.css({'background':'none', 'font-size':defaultSize + 'px', 'color':'black'});
```

Not only it's error prone, but more difficult to maintain, if you use css:

```
.active { background:#AE00000; font-size:15px; color:red }
```

then in your javascript

```
myobj.addClass('active');
```

to toggle off

```
myobj.removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
myobj.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/defacer/pkZTa/)**.

Answer (score 3):

Use `none`

```
myobj.css('background', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say, this will be a good way

```
myobj.css({
  'background': 'none', //remove all the background property
  'backgroundColor': '#FFF' //then only set the background color property
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`css('background', 'none')` would be your best bet: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzEbS/1/)